# Should the [thermostat-c-wire] tag have a [c-wire] synonym?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Earlier today, [@gregmac](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/157/gregmac) created the [thermostat-c-wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermostat-c-wire) tag (and its [tag wiki](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/thermostat-c-wire/info)) and applied it to all the questions that we have about "C" wires.

A couple of times, I had thought about doing the same when I saw these questions come up on the home page, except the tag I was thinking of adding was [c-wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-wire).  I believe [thermostat-c-wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermostat-c-wire) is the better tag because it's more descriptive.  However, to date most of the people asking these questions are new users (13 of the 17 OPs), and might not realize how the tagging system works here: that they'd need to add both [thermostat](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermostat) and [thermostat-c-wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermostat-c-wire).

To that end, would creating a synonym [c-wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-wire) for the main tag [thermostat-c-wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermostat-c-wire) be useful?

Comment: I'm happy to set it up if others agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there weren't any objections, I've setup the [synonym](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/thermostat-c-wire/synonyms) for this.